# C/C++ reading from a char buffer to populate a struct

Tags: c++, c, sockets, struct, scanf

I have a message which is sent over a UDP socket. The message is of type RPCMessage

```
typedef struct
{
    enum {Request, Reply} messageType;
    unsigned int RPCId;
    unsigned int procedure;
    int arg1;
    int arg2;
} RPCMessage;
```

when I send am preparing to send a message, I construct the message as follows:

```
RPCMessage toSend = {RPCMessage::Reply, htonl(rpcId), htonl(procedureId), htonl(int1), htonl(int2);
```

When I receive the message, it is received into a char[] I call buffer. It has been suggested that rather than just casting the entire buffer to an RPCMessage, it would be better to have something where I read each argument from the buffer one by one and then could have the first argument as the correct enum type and use ntohl on each other argument. Would the best way to do this just be something like:

```
RPCMessage::messageType type;
unsigned int id, procedure;
int int1, int2;
sscanf(buffer, %d%d%d%d%d, type, id, procedure, int1, int2);
RPCMessage received = {type, ntohl(id), ntohl(procedure), ntohl(int1), ntohl(int2));
```

or is there another/better way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use a robust serialization framework like boost serialization.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

It depends how complex your messages can get.

Comment: The messages aren't going to be that complex (see the above definition of an RPCMessage... it's 1 enum and a few ints). Are there any common library facilities or anything that might work? I feel like for a fairly small program like mine learning/using an entire serialization framework might be overkill.

Comment: If there are no pointers or non POD types then yeah, it is probably overkill to use boost.
The only problem I see using sscanf is that information is sent on text, and that is not optimal for bandwidth. Again, if the messages are small and in not a great volume, it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend casting to structs. Primary reason - performance.

You can almost always achieve binary compatibility between the layout of your struct and the data in your buffer. There are pragmas that control padding and alignment, etc. In C++ there are special alignment specification for that.

I do not want to say `just cast and problems will disappear`. You still need to handle byte order, character repr can be different, etc.

Serialization should be used when you want to have **different** repesentaion of your structs or when your data structure is complex, like a tree of structures.

Comment: I disagree with your statement of `You can almost always achieve binary compatibility` - since when? Have you ever worked in a multi arch environment?

Comment: Casting to a struct is fast, but very unportable. You have structure packing issues, byte swapping issues, boundary requirements, etc, that differ between machines and compilers.

Comment: Well, I worked. There is `#if` for that. Moving binary structures between different platforms is always an additional effort.

Comment: Not if the *code* that reads them is *written* to be portable. When done properly, you *can* write portable code that still performs, but it takes more care and discipline than #if platform-defined brings. I've personally watched contractors at TATA #if block seven-platforms deep when 'porting' code, and all you get from it is a mess. Do it right, do it once, and it will *always* work.

Comment: "When done properly" is too abstract. `#if` can be easily abused. Nevertheless this is not a reason to stop using it. Binary layout of the structures is not portable without an effort.